# Detecting "unlikely" locations in an application similar to Google Location History

Tags: javascript, google-maps, google-maps-api-3, geolocation

I am currently writing a small geolocation application, quite similar to [Google Location History](https://maps.google.com/locationhistory/b/0). An Android phone regularly sends its position to a server, and I can then show them on a map. I use the JavaScript API 3, and it works quite well. However...

[image: result sample]

As you can see, something is wrong : sometimes the location is extremely inaccurate, probably due to the phone switching networks. I would like to get rid of those "bad locations", to display a clean path, and I haven't figured how to do yet.

**How can I detect if a location is obviously false ?**

It is pretty obvious from a human point of view, unfortunately my computer doesn't think that way yet.

- One solution could be to use the function `computeHeading(from:LatLng, to:LatLng)` from `google.maps.geometry.spherical` to detect very sharp angles in fast succession and act accordingly ; however, I don't really know how I should do it, as checking the last five points each time seems like it would be a bit inefficient... especially since I have a few thousand points to deal with.
- Another thing could be to estimate travel speed, and ignore points involving a sudden and irrealistic acceleration.
- Maybe I could check if the point is within an area defined by his neighbours. It seems reasonable to assume that each position should be somewhere between the one before and the one after, like in the example below.

[image: example circle]

Any help would be appreciated.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

So I decided to go with the third method I thought of : testing if the marker is within a circle defined by two other markers. Basic geometry, Pythagorean theorem. Here's my code :

```
function isLikely(testedPos, pos1, pos2) {
    var hypothenuse = calcDistance(pos1, pos2);
    var side1 = calcDistance(testedPos, pos1);
    var side2 = calcDistance(testedPos, pos2);
    if (hypothenuse*hypothenuse*1.2 >= side1*side1 + side2*side2)
        return true;
    else
        return false;
}
```

`calcDistance` is just an alias for `google.maps.geometry.spherical.computeDistanceBetween()`. Because I'm lazy.

That works just fine !